# Recent form football results in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

What Do I have already:

Table 1: Teams

Table 2: Results 
Table 3: Fixtures

Results has the following columns:

- Match_id
- Date
- HomeTeam
- AwayTeam
- HomeScore
- AwayScore

I want to make a 4th table with a list of the teams and next to it the SUM of their goals scored and goals against in their last 5 games played ( no difference between home or away, so just their last 5 games overall ).

I have found some pieces of code but those are only searching for a team in 1 column and not 2 like in my example.

Can you guys share some ideas for this matter?

Comment: you probably need to tell us what language you are using, and what "2" means (in your example).  Also, a bunch of code snippets would help.

Comment: well I'm working with mysql. 

The results table has a column home team and a column away team.

I have a bunch of code snippets that only can search for a team in 1 column for their last 5 games. But in my case I need a piece of code that searches for a team in the column home team and the column away team . This to find their last 5 games played.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pure MySQL language I suspect it to be something like:

```
INSERT INTO newTable
SELECT team_id, team_name AS teamName FROM Teams
INNER JOIN
SELECT *
    CASE teamName 
        WHEN HomeTeam THEN HomeScore
        WHEN AwayTeam THEN AwayScore
    END AS totalScore
FROM Results
WHERE Match_id = 'last five'
```

If you provide the code snippets that you've got I will be able to help you better.

Comment: this is sth I found ealier today, but in this snippet they search in 1 particular column

SELECT p_id, avg(score) as avg_score
FROM (
  SELECT p_id, score FROM log ORDER BY time LIMIT 3
)
GROUP BY p_id

Comment: edited my answer, check if this suits you. However, it doesn't involve summing up the score. In order to change that I suppose the totalScore should be surrounded with brackets

Answer (score 0):

You can try a case statement:

```
SELECT 
  CASE HomeTeam WHEN 'BlueJays' THEN HomeScore ELSE AwayScore END as 'teamScore'
FROM
  results
WHERE
  // ... add matching date range
```